# Pavilion 15-cb060sa not booting after RAM upgrade

Tags: windows-10, bios, fan, nvidia-geforce, hp-pavilion

I ordered 8gb of new ddr4 to add to my laptop as it said in the manual it was capable of 16gb. It arrived today and i took apart my laptop, done some maintenance (blew dust out of fans, new thermal compound) added the new stick of ram into the free slot, put it back together to start it up and it wont start. The fans run on full speed on startup and eventually i get a 90d error code which says it is a thermal shutdown, but the laptop isnt hot in any way. I tried removing the new stick of ram and booting with only the original stick, and even checking to see if i used too much thermal compound but i still have the same problem.

Update:

I have been able to get it to boot but only once I exit the UEFI system diagnostics. Once I get onto windows the 16gb of ram is showing and working but now my Nvidia gpu isnt detected.

Comment: What diagnostics did you get when it wouldn't start? Normally there are beeps from the bios or light on the motherboard ...

Comment: All i get is a (90D) over temperature shutdown error with a black screen then the laptop proceeds to enter a boot loop. There arent any beeps when i start up.

Comment: Applying thermal compound may have caused the issue if the CPU or GPU were disturbed (e.g. one or more connection broken).

Comment: I think ive come the the conclusion the gpu is fried, any tips or fixes from anyone ? Means i dont need to get a new pc :(

Comment: Take it apart again and check your work.

Comment: I have taken it apart and cleaned off some thermal compund, there was a plastic mask over the gpu and i took it off and there was some compound stuck under it covering some tiny chips, I tried cleaning some off with no luck. I seen a video of someone applying some liquid flux and heating it to clean some of the tiny connections does anyone recommend this or is it a bad idea ?